# uint16_t uint8_t or size_t?

Tags: c, linux, casting, uint8t

I would like to use a function which is charged to send both "data size" and "data" to a specific file descriptor by using `write()`. It works when the record length is equal to 2 bytes. However, I would like to use the same function to send also record length equal to 1 byte.

```
send_func(int port)
{
    void *fd;
    uint64_t fsize = 2517283;
    uint64_t nbrBytes = 0;  
    uint16_t rsize;
    int count;
    ssize_t ret;
    uint8_t Bsent = 0;

    for (count = 1; nbrBytes < fsize; count++) 
    {
        rsize = ((uint8_t*)fp)[nbrBytes];
        rsize += ((((uint8_t*)fp)[nbrBytes + 1]) << 8) & 0xFF00;
        nbrBytes += 2;

        // send size
        ret = write(port, rsize, 2);
        if (ret != 2) {
            return -1;
        }
        // send data
        ret = write(port, ((unsigned char*)fp) + Bsent, rsize - Bsent);
        if (ret < 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        Bsent += ret;
    }
}
```

---

```
send_func(int port)
{
    void *fd;
    uint64_t fsize = 2517283;
    uint64_t nbrBytes = 0;  
    size_t rsize;
    int count;
    ssize_t ret;
    uint8_t Bsent = 0;

    for (count = 1; nbrBytes < fsize; count++) 
    {
        if (mode == ONLY_1_BYTE) {
            rsize = ((uint8_t*)fp)[nbrBytes];
            rsize += ((((uint8_t*)fp)[nbrBytes + 1])); 
            nbrBytes += 1;

            do {
                // send data
                ret = write(port, ((unsigned char*)fp) + Bsent, rsize - Bsent);
                if (ret < 0) {
                    return -1;
                }  
                Bsent += ret;
            } while(Bsent < rsize)     
        }
        else
        {
            rsize = ((uint8_t*)fp)[nbrBytes];
            rsize += ((((uint8_t*)fp)[nbrBytes + 1]) << 8) & 0xFF00;
            nbrBytes += 2;   

            // send size
            ret = write(port, rsize, sizeof(uint16_t));
            if (ret != 2) {
                return -1;
            }        
        }

        do {
            // send data
            ret = write(port, ((unsigned char*)fp) + Bsent, rsize - Bsent);
            if (ret < 0) {
                return -1;
            }  
            Bsent += ret;
        } while(Bsent < rsize)
    }
}
```

Because there is only 1 length byte in the second case, I voluntarily removed the endianity operation, which is compulsory in case of 2 bytes.

Is it the best way to practice ?

Comment: How is record_size declared and assigned?  Your code also never updates `Bsent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some best practices that you can apply to improve the code you posted:

- Don't worry about optimizing a single byte out of the stream.  It doesn't matter.  Did you know that every Ethernet frame takes about 60 bytes of overhead aside from your payload?
- Don't hand-roll endian swaps.  Use built in functions like `htons()`.
- You need to account for "short writes" where the return value from `write()` is less than you tried to send.  When that happens you need to loop and call `write()` again without re-sending a length prefix.